Flutter ml face kit How can you tell if your face is blocked by something?
I need to determine that the face is clearly visible and uncovered. For example, if the mouth is covered by a hand. How can this be determined using ml face kit ?
I tried to do it through Landmark, but you can see them even if you cover some part of your face
